# How to connect signal from a different class?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

```
// splashscreen.h
class SplashScreen : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SplashScreen(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~SplashScreen();

QTimer *mtimer;

public slots:
    void update();

private:
    Ui_SplashScreen *ui;
};
```

---

```
// app.h
#include "splashscreen.h"
class App: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    App(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~App();

    SplashScreen s;

private:
    Ui::AppClass ui;
};
```

---

```
// app.cpp
App::App(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);    

    QGraphicsOpacityEffect* eff = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect();
    s.centralWidget()->setGraphicsEffect(eff);

    QPropertyAnimation* a = new QPropertyAnimation(eff, "opacity");
    a->setDuration(2000);
    a->setStartValue(0);
    a->setEndValue(1);
    a->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);

    s.show();    

    connect(a, &QAbstractAnimation::finished, this, [this]
    { 
        auto *timer = new QTimer();
        this->s.mtimer = timer;
        QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this->s, SLOT(update()));
        timer->start(100);    
    });
}
```

---

I'm getting an error at this line: `QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this->s, SLOT(update()));`

`no instance of overloaded function "QObject::connect" matches the argument list`

[image]

I think it's mismatching the class signal, as `this` passed to the lambda refers to `App` not `SplashScreen`.

When i try to pass `s` (SplashScreen) to the lambda:

```cpp
connect(a, &QAbstractAnimation::finished, this, [s]
{ ... }
```

I get an error: `App::s` is not a variable.

I'm confused, what is the proper way to connect in this case?

Comment: You may want to review the part of [ask] that suggests asking your question *before* posting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App class, s is an instance, not a pointer to an instance. Function connect needs  pointer, not reference.

Use these syntax should help:

```
QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, &s, &SplashScreen::update);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these syntax:

```
QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &SplashScreen::update);
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error as before, I think its needs to refer to `SplashScreen` where you have `this`, I tried:   `connect(a, &QAbstractAnimation::finished, this, [this] {  auto *timer = new QTimer();       this->s.mtimer = timer;      QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this->s, &SplashScreen::update);   }` `this` in this case refers to the `App` class, that's what I said before i was confused about how to reference to `SplashScreen` in this case.

Comment: `QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, SplashScreen, &SplashScreen::update);` also didn't work.